# Python Json Post to Server - bit9

Tags: arrays, json, python-2.7, api, arraylist

i am trying to create a variable in a python dictionary and post this variable to the a server in a json format to a server.
the server isn't accepting a dict containing a list.

this is the code:

```
b9RuleData = {'hash': 'fea66a01c8091683539597d529557b8f2f21270e', 'fileState': 3, 'policyIds' : '11' }
b9RuleData2 = {'hash':'ff9586097b762b7d534cad008fc5f0382b5dcff8', 'fileState': 3, 'policyIds' : '12'}
b9RuleData3 = {'hash':'fea66a01c8091683539597d529557b8f2f21270e', 'fileState': 3, 'policyIds' : '13'}
```

So, what's the best way to write this ? Let's assume that,I have 100 file hashes. I can't keep adding each individual file hash..

Comment: Server language ?

Comment: What do u mean "the server isn't accepting a dict containing a list" dict or json ?

Comment: the server is accepting json. but I am trying to figure how to send multiple json data as the same time.. if that makes sense